# `github workflow run` forcing me to give a value for non-required value

Tags: github-actions, github-cli

I have a GitHub action that is only run manually for creating a build and publishing it either to PyPI or to Test PyPI (or both)

```
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      pypi:
        description: 'Release to PyPI'
        required: false
        default: false
        type: boolean

      test_pypi:
        description: 'Release to Test PyPI'
        required: false
        default: true
        type: boolean
```

When I attempt to start this workflow using the CLI:

```
$ gh workflow run publish-to-pypi.yml --ref master
could not create workflow dispatch event: HTTP 422: Provided value '' for input 'pypi' not in the list of allowed values ...
```

When I include a value of `pypi`, everything works okay:

```
$ gh workflow run publish-to-pypi.yml --ref master -f pypi=false
```

It seems strange that I need to give a value for `pypi`, but not for `test_pypi`, even though both are `required: false`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it is still open bug on github platform
[GitHub Issues](https://github.com/cli/cli/issues/5246)

The workaround is to always supply values even for optional Boolean fields.

Comment: Thanks. It's good to know I wasn't doing anything stupid. My first time using "gh".